# Flex SockMonitor slow initializing

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

It seem to be buggy for 2 situations,

I declare a timer for the socket

```
private var socketTimer:Timer = new Timer(500,1);
```

Code 1:
This code took a few seconds before executing NativeProcess

```
public function onTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void {
    socketMonitor = new SocketMonitor('127.0.0.1',8090);
    socketMonitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, socketStatusChange);
    socketMonitor.start();
}

private function socketStatusChange(e:StatusEvent):void {
    if(socketMonitor.available==false && xSo_start==false) {
        xSo_start=true;
        xSoDump();      //Execute NativeProcess EXE
    }
}
```

Code 2 (Optimize):
This code will execute NativeProcess immediately but after a few mins, NativeProcess will hang by itself without any error:

```
public function onTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void {
    socketMonitor = new SocketMonitor('127.0.0.1',8090);
    socketMonitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, socketStatusChange);
    socketMonitor.start();
    xSoDump();
}
private function socketStatusChange(e:StatusEvent):void {
}
```

In certain situation, NativeProcess will hang itself too, this lead me to wonder if anyone encounter the same issse?

Answer (score 0):

The `NativeProcess` might be pausing whilst it waits for you to read from the StandardOutput or StandardError stereams (especially if the NativeProcess is a command-line application). This might be what you are seeing as the NativeProcess "hanging".

You should read from the StandardOutput/StandardError streams to empty the buffers, even if you are not actually doing anything with the data.

Have a look at the documentation to see how they are handling the `ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA` and `ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA` events (and error handlers):
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html#includeExamplesSummary

Otherwise, are you able to provide more information on what the `NativeProcess` is doing?

Comment: Hi, the native process will be handle lot of incoming data from an application build with JAVA, the native process will not be reading, instead the application will pass the message to XMLSocket using 127.0.0.1 port 8090.

To be clearer, xSoDump() is used to execute NativeProcess, I'm suspected that SocketMonitor auto close afer a limit time out when it failed to capture any data.